In John 14:1, why does Jesus tell us to believe in him along with God, if he isn't personally God himself?
John 14:1

“Do not let your hearts be troubled. Believe in God; believe also
in me."

Thus, according to scripture we should believe in God, and also in his firstborn Son, whom he sent into the world.
However, if Jesus is God, why did He tell us that in addition to believing in God, we must also believe in him?
In other words, How can the one whom God sent also be God?

(I checked before posting, and this particular question has never been asked before.)

I think that is the reason - because Jesus is God, He wants people to believe in Him just as they believe in God - see John 5:23.

Dottard, why didn't he just say, "Believe in the Father, believe also in me"? (And claim they are both God)? How can that be if he is God's Son?

All these questions, "why this or why that." if He isn't already God himself. Or If Jesus is God why did He not know the day of His own return? Why does it escape your notice that God the Father consistently said things that gives His Son credibility as to His true identity. Often directly affirming Jesus as His "ONLY" begotten Son as in there are no others, affirming Him as the predicted Messiah through pronouncements, visions, the baptism of Jesus and the transfiguration. Or the miracles, healings and even raising the dead. Jesus never said, "I am God," because there is only ONE God. Heb 1:8

Mr.Bond, the term "only-begotten" means the firstborn or "most precious" of the progenitor. God certainly has other sons, as the angels are called "Sons of God" and we are adopted as sons of God by faith in God and Christ. Paul could do miracles– and does that make him God? Of course not. Jesus did miracles because God's Spirit was working inside of him!

Why would I want to know a second human if I already know one human already ? How can one human, sent by another human, also be human ? Surely persons may share the same nature.

You yourself edited a Q asking this same thing only 4 days ago. This means you know full well that the same Q has been asked before, and very recently. You added to the Q the point that, surely if Jesus is the offspring of God, he must be God. Many answers given actually answer this new Q of yours. hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/44492/…

One of many examples of the fact that Jesus is not God and never claimed to be. Any common sense reading of the scriptures forbids such a notion - which is why Orthodoxy hinges on redefining terms

The people to whom Jesus spoke were being given his final exhortations before he would depart from them. The verse in question is near the start of a long discourse. The answer to the question is shown throughout the previous 38 verses of Jesus' explanations, and in the following 116 verses. There are a total of 154 verses which, in total, give the contextual answer to the question.
To cut to the chase, the direct answer is that the disciples had already come to believe in this man, Jesus, being the promised Messiah, both Son of God and Son of Man. They knew they were not looking at God, who is Spirit, but they knew this man was the Messiah who had miraculously come in the flesh, but now he said he was departing to return from whence he had come. The start of the answer to the question is in John 13:1:

"Now before the feast of the passover, when Jesus knew that his hour
was come that he should depart out of this world unto the Father,
having loved his own which were in the world, he loved them unto the
end." John 13:1 A.V.

Simon Peter asked him (13:36-37) where he was going, and why he could not follow Jesus there. The verse in question follows, but it is the next verse that begins to make sense of what Jesus meant:

"Let not your heart be troubled: ye believe in God, believe also in
me. In my Father's house are may mansions: if it were not so, I would
have told you. I go to prepare a place for you." (14:1-2)

Then begins Jesus careful explanation as to what, exactly, he meant by that. At no point in the discourse does Jesus say, "I am personally God myself", for the entire being of God had not decanted into one human body; it was the Son of God who had left the Father's side in heaven to be born of the virgin Mary. That is why Jesus went on to explain how

"I am the way, the truth, and the life: no man cometh unto the Father,
but by me. If ye had known me, ye should have known my Father also:
and from henceforth ye know him, and have seen him... he that hath
seen me hath seen the Father." (14:6-9)

Later on in that long explanation, he says that he goes to the Father, and that they will not see him any more (16:10) but whatever they ask the Father (who is in heaven), in the name of Jesus, the Father will grant (16:23). Jesus adds that the Father loves them because they love him, and believe that he came out from God, and that he came forth from the Father, came into the world and will leave the world to return to the Father (16:26-28).
Just as clearly, Jesus says in prayer which he addresses to "Father", such things as:

"And now, O Father, glorify thou me with thine own self with the glory
which I had with thee before the world was." (17:5)

Once those isolated verses quoted above are read in context of the whole 154 verses of Jesus' explanatory speech and prayer, the answer becomes clear. To believe in him is to believe in the Father who sent him. And the Father will love all who so believe in his Son, for to love the Son is to love the Father. Then the Father and the Son will make their abode with such believers (John 14:23 & 10:28 & 2 John verse 9.) It is only because the Son is the Father's chosen means of declaring God that sense can be made of all that Jesus said; this is how the one whom God sent was, indeed, God incarnate:

"No man hath seen God at any time; the only begotten Son, which is in
the bosom of the Father, he hath declared him."  John 1:18

Of course, if anyone says, "That doesn't make sense to me, so I'm not going to believe it", the final discourse and prayer of Jesus on Earth will remain full of questions, not answers.

Good edits; my numbers always need checking! [Why can't I address this to the editor?]

Why would I want to know a second human if I already know one human already ? How can one human, sent by another human, also be human ?
Surely persons may share the same nature.

Paul said of the Son :

being in form, God ; he thought it not robbery to be equal God [Philippians 2:6 KJV]


ος εν μορφη θεου υπαρχων ουχ αρπαγμον ηγησατο το ειναι ισα θεω [TR]

Being of the same nature as Deity he thought it not improper to be equivalent in Deity.
And John says of him who was manifested :

the life the eternal which was with the father [1 John 1:2 KJV]


την ζωην την αιωνιον ητις ην προς τον πατερα  [TR]

Being of the same nature (eternal and living) he was with the father, therefore he was son. Therefore partaking of a begetting which was eternal.
These Divine Persons share the same nature.

Therefore, if one believes in God the Father, one must, of necessity, purposefully also believe in God the Son.
And if the Father, he in divine nature, sent the Son, who is also of divine nature, sending him in humanity, in order to save those found in human nature, is this not wholly understandable ?

The term "God the Son" is nowhere in Scripture.

@OneGodOneLord Correct, it doesn't; it is part of Church Doctrine Wiki: God the Son.)

The disciples' recognition of Jesus as God evolved over time. John the Baptist witnessed the Holy Spirit descending on Jesus (John 1:32), and declare Jesus as the Son of God (or God's Chosen One). However, he later had doubts while in jail (Matthew 11:1-6). Nathanael might have been the first to recognize Jesus as the Son of God (John 1:49), and in general, all disciples might have initially seen Jesus as the figure of the Messiah, the king of Israel (John 1:41).
A significant moment occurred when Simon Peter received divine revelation and proclaimed Jesus as the Messiah, the Son of the living God in Matthew 16:16-17. However, the most pivotal moment was in John 20:28, when Thomas met the resurrected Jesus and exclaimed "My Lord and my God".
Jesus fully recognized that His disciples were not ready to understand His divine nature. In John 14:1, He stated, "Believe in God, believe also in me", meaning that when they believed in God, they should believe that Jesus was sent by God. Jesus frequently communicated to His disciples that He was sent by the Father. Knowing that the disciples struggled to grasp its significant, Jesus elaborated on its meaning in John 14:9-14:

9 Jesus answered: “Don’t you know me, Philip, even after I have been among you such a long time? Anyone who has seen me has seen the Father. How can you say, ‘Show us the Father’? 10 Don’t you believe that I am in the Father, and that the Father is in me? The words I say to you I do not speak on my own authority. Rather, it is the Father, living in me, who is doing his work. 11 Believe me when I say that I am in the Father and the Father is in me; or at least believe on the evidence of the works themselves. 12 Very truly I tell you, whoever believes in me will do the works I have been doing, and they will do even greater things than these, because I am going to the Father. 13 And I will do whatever you ask in my name, so that the Father may be glorified in the Son. 14 You may ask me for anything in my name, and I will do it.

Simon Peter's moment may illustrate that without divine revelation, it is challenging to recognize Jesus as God. This is why Jesus asked the Father for the Advocate, the Holy Spirit, to live with His disciple (John 14:16). The Holy Spirit would teach them all things and remind them of everything Jesus had said to them (John 14:26), so they would have peace and be free from trouble (John 14:27).

@VingentWong, the Father's Holy Spirit inside Christ is God in Christ. When Thomas said, "My Lord, and my God", he wasn't calling his Lord his God, rather, he was addressing his Lord and his God inside his Lord who raised him.

Jesus called his God "my God" too. So is the God of Thomas  different from the God of his teacher Jesus?

@OneGodOneLord At Matthew 3:13-14 Jesus  at Jordan to be baptized by John. At vs14 John tried to "PREVENT" Him from being baptized and John said, "I need to be baptized by you." When the Holy Spirit descended on Jesus, it identified Him as the Messiah and led Him during His ministry. Since you do not believe in the Deity of Jesus Christ who, (btw) was born by the agency of the Holy Spirit and He was sinless how do you account for Jesus at John 20:22 breathing on His disciples saying, "Receive the Holy Spirit?" And at John 20:28 Thomas specifically addresses Jesus, and says, My Lord and my God.

@AlexBalilo – Excellent point! Blessings.

Short Answer (As per another Religion's definition of GOD:
God is one. God is the absolute and only Truth, Has no Physical Form, He is immortal,He is omni present, everywhere, does not die , was never born, the only entity unchangeable, ultimate Truth (everything else is temporary on cosmic time scale). God is the creator of the Universe. God is without hate and prejudice, God does not punish non-believers & sinners, God is not judgemental, God Resides in every living creature big or small. different religions and belief systems are just a pathway to believe in that one Universal God, that path is even for Jesus to seek his God.
with Love2 Humanity.

I am new here and I do hope my answer is quite adequate.

How can the one whom God sent also be God?

To summarize it, The Son is The Father's Voice/Word. The Father is Spirit and cannot be contained by any vessel. The Father's Voice/Word emanates from HIM through The Son, also controlling everything HE does(John 5:19). The Son only tells us to know, serve, and give glory only to The Father, YHWH(Mark 12:29-30, John 17:3). The Son is manifestation of The Father's Voice, like a microphone.
HIS Voice is called "Son" because the first thing The Father did was speak.(Genesis 1:3) It was The Father's Voice who created the Heavens and Earth(Psalm 33:6, Hebrews 11:3), it was The Father's Voice who called Abram, it was The Father's Voice who spoke to Moses from the burning bush, and it was The Father's Voice who spoke to the Israelites from the fire on The Mountain. This means the owner of this Voice gave HIS Name in Exodus 3:15, which is the same as The Son's. Who is the owner of this Voice? Ask yourself this.
We are told The Son is the "Logos", which is usually translated into "Word" but can also be "Speech", and that The "Logos" was with HIM/Elohim from the beginning(John 1:1-2). The Son is called the "firstborn of all creation"(Colossians 1:15). The Son is called the "Author of Life"(Acts 3:15). We are also told that Elohim spoke through The Son to us, whom through The Son the universe was made(Hebrews 1:1-2).
The Son is not The Father(Elohim) Himself, but rather the manifestation(John 1:14) of The Father's Voice foretold on Deuteronomy 18, for The Son was this "Prophet" like Moses(John 1:45, Acts 3:22-23). This is how The Son can ask to believe in HIM, because to believe in The Father you must go through The Son(John 14:6), meaning to listen and follow HIM, The Son is the "Gate"(John 10:9).
Deuteronomy 18-18-19 - Literal Standard Version

I raise up for them a Prophet like you out of the midst of their
brothers, and I have given My words in His mouth, and He has spoken to
them all that which I command Him; 19and it has been [that] the man
who does not listen to My words which He speaks in My Name, I require
[it] of him.

Hebrews 12:25 - Literal Standard Version

Watch out lest you refuse Him who is speaking, for if those did not
escape who refused him who was divinely speaking on earth—much less we
who turn away from Him who [speaks] from Heaven,

Hence, the one speaking on Earth was Moses and the One who speaks from heaven is The Son. For it is the Father speaking through The Son.

Who fancied this ill-advised “if” that creates the irrelevant condition: “if he is not personally God himself”? Lord Jesus Christ is personally God, albeit not God-Father nor God-Holy Spirit.
To show why the question is wrongly put see this analogy: “why mother asks to be respected just as the father is respected if she is not personally the parent herself?” It is wrongly put, because mother is personally parent 100%, just as the father is; similarly hypostasis of Father is 100% God as is the hypostasis of the Son.

God bless you and your loved ones.

@OneGodOneLord thanks! Blessings to you too! All promises and blessings Father can give, with ontological necessity, only through His Logos - Christ (2 Cor. 1:20), which necessity necessitates all honest exegetes to affirm Christ’s divinity. As to the neo-Arians’ cowardly downvotings, without any substantiation, for they have none, it is far from even elementary human decency.

LevanGugineishvili – I do affirm Christ's divinity as a divine god equal to the Father, but not that he was co-eternal with the Father. The Son was begotten of the Father before the world, created as his first son. A son is an offspring, a begotten one. Jesus is the firstborn of all creation.

@OneGodOneLord That cannot hold: just as Father cannot, ontologically cannot, fulfill His promises and blessings but through Christ, so also Father cannot create anything but through His Logos; which means that Logos is uncreated and as uncreated so also co-eternal with Father. To say that Father can create anything without His Logos co-creating this thing, is as preposterous as to say that the sun can enlighten anything without its rays. Moreover, if the Son demands equal worship with Father, unless He is co-eternal to the Father, He cannot demand this in principle.
